# Tabs are not working properly but the code looks fine in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

While coding with HTML5, I have added tabs to the program. At the beginning, it was working fine but now after I Have added some Database code it's not working.

All the elements inside the tabs are not displaying and I don't know what happened.

Here is my code:

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" name="Login" >

<div class="loginBox">    

    <img src="Images/logox.png" class="user"/>   <div class="tab"><button class="tablinks" onclick="openLog(event, 'Login')">Login</button><button class="tablinks" onclick="openLog(event,'Register')">Register</button>   <div id="Login" class="tabcontent"> <h2> Please log in</h2>
       <p>Email</p>
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="name@domain.com" id="txteml"/>
        <p> Password</p>
        <input type="password" name="text" placeholder="Enter password" id="txtpass"  />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="./WebForm2.aspx"> Forget password</a></div>

   <div id="Register" class="tabcontent">

    <h2> create your acount </h2>
    <p>Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder=" First Name last Name"  id="txtname" />
    <p>Email</p>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" id="textEmail" " pattern="([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$" title="Email in correct form" /> 
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="text" placeholder="Enter password" id="textPass"   title="Password must contains eight characters, at least one letter, one number and one special character" pattern="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? this.title : '');if(this.checkValidity()) form.pwd2.pattern = RegExp.escape(this.value);"/>
    <p> Confirm Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="text"   placeholder="Enter the same password" id="ConPass" title="Please enter the same Password as above" pattern="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? this.title : '');"/>
    <p>Company</p> 
      <br /><select  id="comp"><option >x</option><option>d</option</select><br /><br /><p>Department</p> <br /><select  id="dept"><option  >nn</option><option  >mm</option></select> 
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" Id="reg" onclick="Insert()" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <h1> Thank You!</h1></div></div></div>
</form>
```

The JavaScript part

```
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    function openLogin(evt, logName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(logName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
```

[image: this is the screenshot]

What shall I do?

Comment: What are the errors you have in the console?

Comment: its doesn't show me any errors

Comment: What do you mean by `tabs` can you describe your problem better and add screenshots to point out what your problem is?!

Comment: I have added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem at `document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();`, there is no element with the ID `defaultOpen` in your html.

Another problem is, that you are missing a closing bracket for the function `openLogin` in your javascript at the last part.

Try this:

```
var defaultOpen = document.getElementById("defaultOpen");
if (defaultOpen !== null) defaultOpen.click();

function openLogin(evt, logName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(logName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: still not displaying any elements its only showing for me blank tabs

Comment: if I add defaultOpen  the page starting auto refresh